# Screen rotation causes previous class to show

Tags: rotation, android-canvas

Over the last few years I have been dabbling in Java and am teaching myself android. I have a little app and from it can call a canvas where a few lines are drawn. The problem I have is that if I rotate my mobile device the canvas closes and I once again see the previous screen with the button that called the canvas. Here is the code that calls the canvas:

```
            public class Weight_and_Balance extends AppCompatActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button graph;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weight_and__balance);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // 1. Access the Button defined in layout XML
    // and listen for it here
    graph = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showgraph);
    graph.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId())
    {

        case R.id.showgraph:
            // Code for Show Graph button
            Draw draw;
            draw = new Draw(this);
            setContentView(draw);
            break;

    //            case R.id.button2:
    //                // Code for button 2 click
    //                break;
    }

    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService
    (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

}
```

}

Being a newby to this can I pass focus to the called class?
If not how do you remain on the canvas?
The reason for the question is that I spent quite some time getting the rotation to work and redraw the lines based on screen resolution and want to be able to rotate the screen to give either extra width (or height) to the drawn image.
Thank you.
Paul

Comment: You need to more clear and the code is not sufficient. Could you post the simplified code of your `Activity`.

Comment: Post the code as an edit to the question. Also this is the code of the `View`. I was talking about the `Activity`.

Comment: Have I posted what is needed?

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the device, the `Activity` will be recreated. This means that `onCreate()` will be called again. This is why you are having your issue. This in reality, is not an issue at all. You need to make sure that, your `Draw` view is created again if rotated.

1. Call `setContentView()` only once and only inside `onCreate()`. This method is to set a `View` for the entire `Activity`.
2. What you need to do is have the `Draw` view in the `activity_weight_and__balance.xml` and then during onClick(), just set the visibility of this `Draw View` to true.

If you want to persist this during rotation, you need to override the `onSaveInstanceState()` and save things there, and later use the `savedInstanceState` bundle in `onCreate()` to get back what you just saved.

For more info on persisting data on rotation, you can refer the `developers.android.com`